# How do I implement a follower system with private accounts in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, data-structures, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an an app in Firebase with a user feature and I need to implement a system to allow:

- A user to follow another user
- A user to see a list of the users they're following
- A user to set their profile as private so that some of their data is only visible to the people following them
- A user to be able to send a follow request to a user with a private profile
- A user with a private profile to be able to accept/reject follow requests

So far I've made a Firestore collection at the root called `users`. When a user signs up with Firebase Auth, a document is made in `users` with the following structure:

> user (document)
>
> > username: string
> > accountIsPrivate: boolean
> >
> > > userData (collection)
> > >
> > > > userData (document)

where all the data that would be hidden if the account were private is in the `userData` document.

I'm not sure how I could implement the system to fulfill my requirements from here so that I could use Firestore rules to only allow followers of a private account to view that account's `userData`. I would appreciate it if anyone could suggest an appropriate data structure and an outline of how to write rules for this.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of situation, you must maintain two sources of truth, one for the creator and one for the user. this is done with an array of strings in both that have the user_uid and any additional information concatenated.

The goal is to have an array of CSV-like values of which you can split and render within your app.

> create a concat string: `entry = [user.uid, user.name, user.url].join(';');`

> return string to object: `entry.split(';');`

Doing the following ensures that only a unique entry exists

> `db.doc("user/user_id/userData/followers").set({ followers: Firestore.FieldValue.ArrayUnion(entry)}, {merge: true});`

This is only a rough example and some backend logic will be needed to scale large - but with this, you have a theoretical limit of 200k entries depending on how much data you want to store in the string.

Additional logic would involve cloud functions reading and writing when a request to follow has been created which handles a counter that creates new documents as needed and ensure's that the counter is updated to prevent overflow since Security Rules can't do any recursive logic or manipulate the request directly.